# Terraform doesn't understand kubernetes failure

Tags: terraform

I tried to deploy a simple nginx pod with Terraform. The deployment failed because I had a typo in the image name, the problem is Terraform didn't understand the failure.

I waited for 10 minutes, and terraform was spinning. This is not very practical, even if at the end it understands that the deployment fails; I am not sure if this happens as I didn't wait that long.

How do you work around this? Terraform is pretty fast if things go right, but in case of problems, it is very slow.

Answer (score 0):

terraform doesnt check validity of the docker image, it just picks up the image name we type in and runs it and may be timeout occurs

Not sure if there is a way to validate the image may be add some manual checks for the image url

Comment: Terraform can see if the deployment failed and report that. I thought that should be possible, because it fails immediately